# Retrieving videos from Temporary Internet Files

Tags: silverlight, temporary-internet-files

I am using a Silverlight application which saves videos under ~\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5 I want to copy these videos out for future viewing.

Under Content.IE5, there are some randomly named folders and videos, scattered among them and there are files with the same name under these folders. I searched for an index.dat file, but it doesn't exist.

How does Windows organize these folders? Where is the information about under which folder a file is stored?

Comment: You do understand in most cases Silverlight is used because it supports DRM right?  Are you sure these videos are not protected by DRM?

Comment: most all videos streamed these days do not allow copying anymore. either they do not store the file and are literally streamed or the files are encrypted to prevent copying, use a third party app or website to download youtube videos, there are plenty available for free.